# check csv every 5 rows with condition using python3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, time

csv data:

```
>c1,v1,c2,v2,Time

>13.9,412.1,29.7,177.2,14:42:01

>13.9,412.1,29.7,177.2,14:42:02

>13.9,412.1,29.7,177.2,14:42:03

>13.9,412.1,29.7,177.2,14:42:04

>13.9,412.1,29.7,177.2,14:42:05

>0.1,415.1,1.3,-0.9,14:42:06

>0.1,408.5,1.2,-0.9,14:42:07

>13.9,412.1,29.7,177.2,14:42:08

>0.1,413.4,1.3,-0.9,14:42:09

>0.1,413.8,1.3,-0.9,14:42:10
```

My current code that I have:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv 
import datetime as dt


#Read .csv file, get timestamp and split it into date and time separately
Data = pd.read_csv('filedata.csv', parse_dates=['Time_Stamp'], infer_datetime_format=True)
Data['Date'] = Data.Time_Stamp.dt.date
Data['Time'] = Data.Time_Stamp.dt.time
#print (Data)
print (Data['Time_Stamp'])
Data['Time_Stamp'] = pd.to_datetime(Data['Time_Stamp'])
#Read timestamp within a certain range
mask = (Data['Time_Stamp'] > '2017-06-12 10:48:00') & (Data['Time_Stamp']<= '2017-06-12 11:48:00')
june13 = Data.loc[mask]
#print (june13)
```

What I'm trying to do is to read every 5 secs of data, and if 1 out of 5 secs of data of `c1` is `10.0` and above, replace that value of `c1` with 0.

I'm still new to python and I could not find examples for this. May I have some assistance as this problem is way beyond my python programming skills for now. Thank you!

Comment: Just a side comment, it is considered to be bad practice to insert space between functions and parameters, such as `print (Data)`. I think you can find something on this in Pep8. (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements)

Comment: I'll get rid of the space and check the link out. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: Also took some more time to try and answer, but I might be completely off on what you are trying to do, just say so if it's the case and, if you give some precision, I'll edit my answer if I can find another solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the modules around csv files so my answer might look primitive, and I'm not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish here, but have you though of dealing with the file textually ?

From what I get, you want to read every c1, check the value and modify it.

**To read and modify the file, you could do:**

```
with open('filedata.csv', 'r+') as csv_file:
    lines = csv_file.readlines()

    # for each line, isolate data part and check - and modify, the first one if needed.
    # I'm seriously not sure, you might have wanted to read only one out of five lines. 
    # For that, just do a while loop with an index, which increments through lines by 5.
    for line in lines:
        line = line.split(',')  # split comma-separated-values

        # Check condition and apply needed change.
        if float(line[0]) >= 10:
            line[0] = "0"  # Directly as a string. 

        # Transform the list back into a single string.
        ",".join(line)

    # Rewrite the file.
    csv_file.seek(0)
    csv_file.writelines(lines)

    # Here you are ready to use the file just like you were already doing.
    # Of course, the above code could be put in a function for known advantages.
```

(I don't have python here, so I couldn't test it and typos might be there.)

**If you only need the dataframe without the file being modified:**

Pretty much the same to be honest. 
Instead of the file-writing at the end, you could do :

```
from io import StringIO  # pandas needs stringIO instead of strings.

# Above code here, but without the last 6 lines.

Data = pd.read_csv(
    StringIo("\n".join(lines)),
    parse_dates=['Time_Stamp'],
    infer_datetime_format=True
)
```

This should give you the Data you have, with changed values where needed.

Hope this wasn't completely off. Also, some people might find this approach horrible ; we have already coded working modules to do that kind of things, so why botter and dealing with the rough raw data ourselves ? Personally, I think that it's often much easier than learning all of the external modules I'll be using in my life if I don't try to understand how the text representation of files can be used. Your opinion might differ.

Also, this code might result in performances being lower, as we need to iterate through the text twice (pandas does it when reading). However, I don't think you'd get faster result by reading the csv like you already do, then iterate through data anyway to check condition. (You might win a cast per c1 checked value, but the difference is small and iterating through pandas dataframe might as well be slower than a list, depending on the state of their current optimisation.)

*Of course, if you don't really need the pandas dataframe format, you could completely do it manually, it would take only a few more lines (or not, tbh) and shouldn't be slower, as the amount of iterations would be minimized : you could check conditions on data at the same time as you read it. It's getting late and I'm sure you can figure that out by yourself so I won't code it in my great editor (known as stackoverflow), ask if there's anything !*

Comment: It is true that I need to read every single line of c1, but what I actually want to do is to read 5 lines at a time, check if there is only 1 value of c1 that is more than 10.0 in those 5 lines, and if the condition is met, replace that value of c1( > 10.0 ) with 0.0. Thanks for sharing your answer too, but I don't think that is what I'm trying to get.

Comment: I first started by implementing what you said in my head, then I realized. If the value you are changing is the one that is larger than 10.0, how would reading 5 differ from reading them one-by-one to check that same condition ? ---- Anyway, if you really want to do it, still, you could iterate through five elements lists using `index` variable and it's end equivalent (index + 5) (be careful, index out of range could occur) and use slices...